# Numbering restarts within document with multiple files

Tags: page-numbering, multiple-files

I am working on a document with multiple files for my thesis. With each file the page and footnotes numbering restarts from 1. Is there a way to make the numbering of pages and citation continue over the files other than resetting it manually.

MWE for the main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{scrextend}
%%%%language settings%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%%%%Fonts%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O C}]{Linux Libertine O}
%%%%%%%pagesetup%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{parskip}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\setlength\parindent{8pt}

%%set space between main text and footnote ruler
\setlength{\skip\footins}{6mm} %<------------ add this
\def\footnoterule{
\kern-3mm \hrule width 2in \kern -.4pt 
\kern 3mm}
%%%no paragraph break %%
%\widowpenalties 1 10000
%\raggedbottom
%%noindent for footnotes%%
%searching .....
\usepackage[flushmargin,hang]{footmisc}
%%%%biblatex%%%%%%
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{»}{«}
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes, isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{literatur/Doktorarbeit.bib}
%%%Bookmarks%%%%
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false,linkcolor=false,urlcolor=false,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{multicol}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%footnote margin%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\deffootnote[0em]{0em}{0em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage\else
  \xpretocmd{\@maketitle}
    {\deffootnote[0em]{0em}{0em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}
  \fi
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%toc bibliography&&
%grafics%%
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{transparent}
%\graphicspath{{grafik/}}
%increase toc depth&
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\input{titelblatt/title.tex}
\tableofcontents


\include{einleitung/einleitung}
\include{kap1/kap1}

\clearpage

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm guessing each "file" here is started with a chapter command. Then that's the one resetting. On modern latex you could use `\counterwithout{footnote} {chapter} ` which removes footnote from being reset by a new chapter

Comment: @daleif Where does this command belong? in each file or in the preamble? And How about the page numbers?

Comment: In the preamble. Did not notice the page number question. You should probably make a complete example, we don't know what is in the included files

Comment: It worked using your suggestion, and the page numbering too, thankx @daleif

Comment: I would like to know what caused the issue with the page numbers. Not sure if subfiles is doing something it shouldn't , but we do not know as we cannot test the code

Comment: @daleif It was actually my mistake as I forgot to delete the command ```\pagenumbering{arabic}``` from the second file

Comment: Now you know why we insist on these complete examples. Would have found that immediately

Comment: I was just about to copy the files to put it here as I discovered the mistake. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbering of the footnote was solved with the suggestion of @daleif  in the comments, (adding `\counterwithout{footnote} {chapter}` to the preamble) the problem with the page numbering is on me, as I used the command `\pagenumbering{arabic}` in the start of each file.